# How to make newtype an instance of monad

Tags: haskell

I am stucked here, I can make `data` types instances of `Monad` but i can't figure out how i can do it with `newtype`.

```
newtype Val a = Val {getVal :: [a]} deriving (Show)

instance Monad Val where
    return = Val
    (>>=) (Val {getVal = l}) f  = map f l
```

If i write like this :

```
instance Monad Val where
return = Val
(>>=) (Val {getVal = l}) f  =  {getVal = map f l}
```

then i get error and it says `parse error on input {`
.

How do i make `newtype` an instance of Monad?

Comment: That definition of `return` doesn't type-check, does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` is the most convenient option here.

A longer alternative is to use safe coercions so to ask Haskell to perform all the wrapping / unwrapping for us automatically. Unfortunately, this requires some manual type annotations and arguments, since otherwise types are too general for the automagic coercions to work.

Not terribly convenient, but there it is.

```
{-# LANGUAGE InstanceSigs, ScopedTypeVariables, TypeApplications #-}

import Data.Coerce

newtype Val a = Val {getVal :: [a]} deriving (Show)

instance Functor Val where
   fmap :: forall a b. (a -> b) -> Val a -> Val b
   fmap = coerce (fmap @ [] @ a @ b)

instance Applicative Val where
   pure :: forall a. a -> Val a
   pure = coerce (pure @ [] @ a)
   (<*>) :: forall a b. Val (a -> b) -> Val a -> Val b
   (<*>) = coerce ((<*>) @ [] @ a @ b)

instance Monad Val where
   return :: forall a. a -> Val a
   return = coerce (return @ [] @ a)
   (>>=) :: forall a b. Val a -> (a -> Val b) -> Val b
   (>>=) = coerce ((>>=) @ [] @ a @ b)
```

Another option would be to manually do the wrapping / unwrapping, which `coerce` automated in the code above. This is quite boring and cumbersome, though. Still, it would require no type annotations or arguments, so at least it would save effort on those.

Comment: This is advance things than i'm learning but i'm glad i learnt something new , thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of issues here. First, you have to specify the record name before the braces. So you want

```
(>>=) (Val {getVal = l}) f = Val {getVal = map f l}
```

Now, neither of your functions is going to typecheck right now. But the fixes aren't too difficult, since you're just delegating to the already-existing list monad instance. Your `return` is close, but you need to wrap the result in a list.

```
return x = Val [x]
```

Likewise, you don't want `map` inside the record. You want the list monad version of `(>>=)`.

```
(>>=) (Val {getVal = l}) f = Val {getVal = l >>= f}
```

Unfortunately, this still won't *quite* typecheck, since `f` is designed to return `Val` and not `[]`. We need to make that correction inside the monad operation.

```
(>>=) (Val {getVal = l}) f = Val {getVal = l >>= getVal . f}
```

After that, you'll likely get errors about `Applicative` being a superclass of `Monad`. That can be solved with a simple application of some helper functions.

```
import Control.Monad

-- ...

instance Functor Val where
    fmap = liftM

instance Applicative Val where
    pure = return
    (<*>) = ap
```

Now everything should compile.

---

As a side note, if you're using GHC, there's a handy feature called `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` that will give you instances for `newtype` data types automatically. You can use it like so

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

newtype Val a = Val {getVal :: [a]}
    deriving (Show, Functor, Applicative, Monad)
```

This only works on `newtype`, not `data`, and it only works in GHC, so don't use it if you intend your code to be portable across compilers.

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide the constructor when constructing an instance of `Val` in the definition of `>>=`:

```
(>>=) (Val {getVal = l}) f = Val {getVal = map f l}
```

Haskell does not have "free" records, the way, say, PureScript does. In Haskell, `{ x = y, v = u }` on its own is not a valid syntax for constructing a record. You need to always provide the constructor, e.g. `C { x = y, v = u }`.

Comment: This will fix the syntax error, but there will still be type errors for both `return` and `(>>=)`.

Comment: Indeed. I was only answering what was noted in the question, did not bother to look further. I will still leave this answer here for completeness.